# turn off "use spaces, do not use tabs" in a jslint extension for VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jslint

I got a VSCode JSLint extension and I got its settings pointing to an .eslintrc file where I have the following specified for indentation:

```
{
    ...
    "indent" : [1, "tab"]
    ...
}
```

The problem is, it's still putting the squiggly green lines where I have some tabs and I can't tell where anything's going wrong with any settings.

I have evidence the rc file is actually working because I was successfully able to change it from single to double-quotes. However it appears to completely ignore the indentation setting  inside my VSCode.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could simply disable the `use_spaces` rule. It's separate from the `indent` rule you changed. A bit over an oversight from JSLint.

There were quite a few complains about that rule, even [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13913189/14274597). Quite a few people (not only on SO) suggest switching to JS**H**int instead. Personally I've only used ESLint and therefore don't know much about the differences, and I'd suggest checking those for yourself anyway.